# Javascript inherit static and instance methods/properties

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

In javascript how would I set up inheritance so that **static** and **instance** properties/methods are inherited?

My goal is to build a base "class" that 3rd parties would inherit from, and be able to call static and instance properties/methods inherited from the base "class".

In my example I define a recipe base class that others can inherit from and create recipes off of:

```
Function.prototype.inherits = function (base) {
  // code to inherit instance and static
  // props/methods here
  var temp = function () { };
  temp.prototype = base.prototype;
  this.prototype = new temp();
}

function Recipe() {
  var self = this;

  Recipe.ingredients = { };

  Recipe.prepare = function (ingredients) {
    // prepare each of the ingredients...
    var preparedIngredients = ingredients;

    Recipe.ingredients = preparedIngredients;
  };

  self.share = function () {
    console.log('Recipe Shared!');
  };
}

Toast.inherits(Recipe);

function Toast() {
  var self = this;
}

var toast = new Toast();

// Child function should inherit static methods
Toast.Prepare({
  bread: '2 slices',
  butter: '1 knob',
  jam: '1 tablespoon'
});

// Child function should inherit static properties
console.log(Toast.ingredients);

// Child function should inherit instance methods as well
toast.share();

// And if I define another it gets its own static properties/methods
// Spaghetti.ingredients !== Toast.ingredients
Spaghetti.inherits(Recipe);

function Spaghetti() {
  var self = this;
}

Spaghetti.prepare({
  noodles: '1 box',
  tomatoes: 2,
  sausage: 1
});
```

Plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/x8rKeKXSxDHMB4CD6j1c

Comment: Why would a `Child` method want to set a property on the `Base.staticProp` object to `'child'`?

Comment: @Bergi see my updated demo. I define a recipe base class for other recipes, i.e. Toast, Spaghetti, etc. What probably confused you was the fact that I wanted every subclass to get its own static property.

Comment: Uh, I think `toast` should be an instance of `Recipe`? The `ingredients` quite certainly don't qualify as a static property.

Comment: @Bergi Let's just say in this case Toast is the basis of all toast so it needs to be a class (it is a model). Other kinds of toast would extend from Toast.

Comment: Hm, but then they still wouldn't share the `.ingredients`. Also, `Recipe` could become a meta-class to produce models, which is a bit complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inheritance is wrong, Toast is not a Recipe it has a Recipe. Ingredients of Recipe cannot be static because a Recipe can be used for toast, pancake or many other dishes.

```
function Recipe(name,ingredients) {
  this.name=name;
  this.ingredients = ingredients;
};

var Toast = function(){}
Toast.prototype.recipe = new Recipe('toast',{
  bread: '2 slices',
  butter: '1 knob',
  jam: '1 tablespoon'
});
```

More info on prototype can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

If you want to inherit static members you need a better example: for example MyDate and MyDateTime.

```
var MyDate=function(dateString){
  this.date=(dateString)?new Date(dateString)
    :new Date();
};
MyDate.YEAR=Date.prototype.getFullYear;
//... others like MONTH, DAY ...
MyDate.prototype.get = function(what){
  if(what && typeof what==='function'){
      return what.call(this.date);
  }
  console.log('nope');
};

var MyDateTime=function(dateString){
  MyDate.call(this,dateString);
};
//set static properties (can write a function for this)
for(mystatic in MyDate){
  if(MyDate.hasOwnProperty(mystatic)){
    MyDateTime[mystatic]=MyDate[mystatic];
  }
}
MyDateTime.HOUR=Date.prototype.getHours;
//instead of breaking encapsulation for inheritance
// maybe just use Object.create and polyfil if needed
// and stop reading DC when it comes to this subject
MyDateTime.prototype=Object.create(MyDate.prototype);
MyDateTime.prototype.constructor=MyDateTime;

var d = new MyDate();
console.log(d.get(MyDate.YEAR));
var dt = new MyDateTime();
console.log(dt.get(MyDateTime.YEAR));
console.log(dt.get(MyDateTime.HOUR));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of static/instance member inheritance. This is using small class framework I wrote to make oop in javascript easier to use and nicer to look at. It's [available on github](https://github.com/digital-synapse/ds.oop) if you are interested.

```
var Base = new ds.class({
    type: 'Base',
    constructor: function() {
        this.instanceprop: 'am i instance?'
    },
    staticprop: 'am i static?'
});

var Example = new ds.class({
    type: 'Example',
    inherits: Base,
    constructor: function() {}
});

var eb = new Base();
var ex = new Example();

console.log( Base.staticprop );
console.log( eb.instanceprop );
console.log( Example.staticprop );
console.log( ex.instanceprop );
```