# why instances doesn't inherit property added to constructor function without prototype keyword

Tags: javascript

in this example a property called 't' is added to speak function.`Speak.t=5;`when i call speak() it prints the value 5 via another function called show.But when i create new instance of Speak it doesn't inherit the property t.Why is that so??i mean if it is a property of Speak constructor all its instances should inherit it??

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function Speak(){

    show(Speak.t);
}
Speak.t=5;
function show(v){
    console.log('value is : '+v);
}
Speak();
var s1=new Speak();
console.log(s1.t);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm positive this *has* to be a duplicate, but I can't find it.

Comment: Speak.something would be static: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253831/javascript-inherit-static-and-instance-methods-properties/25255577#25255577 prototype is shared by instances: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "i mean if it is a property of Speak constructor all its instances should inherit it?"

No. Its instances inherit from the constructor's prototype, not the constructor itself. JavaScript is prototype-based, not "Constructor-based". If you are familiar with [other OOP languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-oriented_programming_languages), `Speak.t` will be *similar* to a public [static property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664451(v=vs.71).aspx).

Changing it to `Speak.protoype.t = 5` will add the property `t: 5` to the prototype which will be inherited to all of its instances:

```
function Speak(){
    show(this.t);
}
Speak.prototype.t = 5;

function show(v){
    console.log('value is : '+v);
}

var s1 = new Speak();    //"value is : 5"
console.log(s1.t);       //5
```

---

Since instances inherit from its constructor's prototype, you can actually achieve class inheritance by doing this:

```
function SpecialSpeak(){}
SpecialSpeak.prototype = new Speak();
```

This creates a `Speak` instance and assign it as the `SpecialSpeak`'s prototype.

```
new SpecialSpeak() instanceof SpecialSpeak;     //true
new SpecialSpeak() instanceof Speak;            //true
```

Since all `Speak` instances will be updated if its prototype has changed, it will also update `SpecialSpeak`'s prototype and also update all `SpecialSpeak`'s instances.

```
var s = new SpecialSpeak();
s.v;                             //undefined
Speak.prototype.v = "text";
s.v;                             //text
```

This demonstrates how inheritance works in JavaScript. The chaining of prototypes is sometimes called a ["prototype chain"](http://books.google.com/books?id=WTZqecc9olUC&pg=PA118).

You might also want to check out [this great article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance) about inheritance.

---

Side note: Since all prototype chains must have a starting point,

```
Object.prototype instanceof Object;    //false
```

Although `Object.prototype` is an object, it is the very top prototype (object) that everything<sup>*</sup> inherits from, therefore it's not an instance of `Object`. It is *the* Object!

<sub><sup>*</sup> Starting from ES5, `Object.create` is introduced which lets you create objects that doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype`.</sub>

Comment: Instance of parent to set prototype part of child and child not re using parent constructor? Would it not be better to refer to an article that shows how to use prototype?

Comment: @HMR - I have added a link to the inheritance article on MDN.

Answer (score 1):

When the `new` operator is called on a constructor function, the JavaScript engine executes a few steps behind the scene:

1. It allocates a new object inheriting from your constructor function's prototype
2. It executes your constructor function, passing the newly created object as `this`
3. If your constructor function returns an object, then it uses it. Otherwise it uses the `this` object.

At no time it considers the class properties attached to the constructor function. This is why `Speak.t = 5` doesn't create an inherited property.

However, those pieces of code will do:

```
// By attaching `t` to the prototype
function Speak1() {}
Speak1.prototype.t = 5;

// By attaching `t` to the newly created object
function Speak2() {
  this.t = 5;
}

// By returning an object containing `t` (thus overriding the formerly allocated this)
function Speak3() {
  return {
    t: 5
  };
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/034nw7j1/1/)

You can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you don't set internally the value of `t`. You should instantiate the value of `t` inside the constructor of Speak like this :

```
function Speak(){
  this.t = 5;
  show(this.t);
}
function show(v){
    console.log('value is : '+v);
}
Speak();
var s1=new Speak();
console.log(s1.t);
```

You could also attach the `show`method inside the constructor to access the prototype of it.

```
var Speak = (function() {
  function Speak() {
    this.t = 5;
    this.show();
  }

  Speak.prototype.show = function() {
    return console.log('value is : ' + this.t);
  };

  return Speak;

})();

var s1=new Speak();
console.log(s1.t);
```

Comment: i didn't understand your second example .you have declared another Speak function  inside another Speak function.it's confusing.little explanation would've been better.thanks anyway..:)

Comment: The `var Speak`will contains the function returned by an auto-executed function. In this auto-executed function, I created the function Speak and attached the `t` property and the `show` function to his prototype. Is it clear now ?

Answer (score 1):

Since functions are just objects `t` becomes a property of the function Speak, which is not shared with the instances.

for e.g functions by default get a property called length ( gives arity of the function)
which will not be shared with the instances.

```
function Speak(){}
var obj = new Speak();
console.log("length" in Speak); // true
console.log("length" in obj); // false
```

you can see quite clearly the length is not shared with the instances.
In javascript the only way to have a property or a method shared is through the prototype pattern.

Creating a property this way, makes it behave like a `static` variable on Speak

Comment: function argument have length property.But how a function itself has a length property.i mean what Speak.length might return??

Comment: for e.g if you a function say function test(a,b){}. test.length will be 2. length gives you the number of parameters that the function can accept . this just asserts the fact that functions are just objects in javascript

Comment: @BOSS - `.length` does not give you the number of parameters that the function can accept. Instead, it returns the number of parameters that the function expected.